# How to call donchian indicator using the getsymbol data

Tags: r, quantmod

I am trying to pull donchian channel but i get subscript error.
I have also tried to reference the code in the other example but it does not work for me.

```
library(quantmod)
my_quote <- getSymbols("MSFT", auto.assign = FALSE)
head(my_quote,5)
dc<- lag(DonchianChannel(my_quote[,c("my_quote.High","my_quote.Low")]))
```

Error in `[.xts`(my_quote, , c("my_quote.High", "my_quote.Low")) :
subscript out of bounds

Comment: There are no columns named `my_quote.High` and `my_quote.Low`. The correct names are `MSFT.High` and `MSFT.Low`, so your code should be `DonchianChannel(my_quote[, c("MSFT.High","MSFT.Low")])`. Wrapping it into a `lag` function still creates an error.

Comment: how do i avoid referring to MSFT and use just the variables?

Comment: overwrite the names, `names(my_quote) <- gsub('.*\\.', '', names(my_quote))`. Then you can refer to them as `High`, `Low` etc.

Answer (score 0):

`quantmod` has a whole bunch of helper functions for accessing the price types  in OHLCV that you should familiarise with. You can then avoid manipulating column name strings. Look at `Op`, `Hi`, `Lo`, `Cl`, `HLC`, `Vo`, `Ad`, `HiCl`, etc.  Take a look at `?HLC`.

The DC needs high and low prices. You could simply do

```
hilo <- merge(Hi(my_quote), Lo(my_quote))
dc<- lag(DonchianChannel(hilo, n = 10))
```